# Tableau server service account (production) - Issue with Extracts

Tags: extract, tableau-api

I am tableau developer, I have created workbook using tableau desktop  which contains multiple dashboards, data sources, while creating workbook I have used Extracts.
Now I have signed in to shared tableau server of my company called "Production" and published my workbook, production does have data base access. 
But I am having problem in refreshing extracts. Extracts are not getting refreshed- tried most of possible ways like Relogin to prod server, checking database connection, checking prod server connections. Can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Note: I do not have my separate credentials for tableau prod server environment, I signin in to Tableau prod sever environment with shared Tableau prod server credentials.
but workbook that is created is in my tableau desktop having my own credentials. 
Second thing when I publish same workbook in Tableau server - (developer environment - which belongs to our project, where I have access and has linked with data base as well, the workbook is properly published and there is no issue with extracts they are timely auto refreshed.

And

Or Share similar publishing to tableau server - prod environment tutorials or videos ?
Or share correct steps to publish dashboard with extract in to prod server environment.

Comment: It could be because the tableau server service account does not have access to the path where you are saving your extracts. If it does, make sure you use the full path name and not shortcuts.

Comment: Ask your site administrator to look at the Background Tasks for Extracts viz on the Status page. It's only available to site and server administrators. There, the admin can see all failed extracts. Hover over the failed extract and the tooltip will include the error message. Without knowing the error message, you'll spin your wheels guessing at what's wrong. See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/adminview_backgrnd.htm.